# Get model instance based on its fields?

Tags: django

My model definition:

```
class Thing1(models.Model):
    thing2s = models.ManyToManyField(Thing2, blank=True)
```

I have an instance of Thing2, called myThing2.
I want to do something like this:

```
Thing1.objects.get(thing2s__contains = myThing2)
```

That doesn't work as functional code, but hopefully you get my point. (I'm trying to find a Thing1 that has myThing2 in it's thing2s field.) How might I do that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would add a 'related_name' to your many to many definition.

Something like

```
class Thing1(models.Model):
    thing2s = models.ManyToManyField(Thing2, blank=True, related_name='thing1s')
```

Then, from your Thing2, you can access the 'thing1s' that it relates to by....

```
thing2.thing1s.all()
```

But,I have to ask, as was stated above, if thing2 can only be related to a single thing1, then you should be using a ForeignKey(in Thing2, instead of Thing1) instead of ManyToMany. But, the above solution still works.

So, your classes would be....

```
class Thing1(models.Model):
    pass

class Thing2(models.Model):
    thing1 = models.ForeignKey(Thing1, blank=True, related_name='thing2s')
```

So, from a thing2, you could get at its single thing1 by simply....

```
a_thing1 = thing2.thing1
```

and from a thing1, you could get a list of all the thing2s that reference it via....

```
thing2s = thing1.thing2s.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't tested but I believe you would say

```
Thing1.objects.filter(thing2s = myThing2)
```

Since more than one Thing1 can have a Thing2, use filter to pull out all of the Thing1s that have a myThing2.

Filter returns a list of Thing1s.

Comment: Well thanks for your help, but actually, my db is made so that a Thing2 can only belong to one Thing1. This main issue is in my "thing2s = myThing2" statement. I somehow have to filter through that thing2s list of Thing2s to see if myThing2 is in that list.

Comment: It sounds like you may actually need to use a ForeignKey rather than a ManyToMany--that's the relation to use in the case you describe.  That being said, if you are using a ManyToMany, lovefaithswing's answer is correct--the thing2s = myThing2 will set up the join to filter  the list of associated Things2s.